# Unable to access outside URL using file() function in PHP

Tags: php, apache, file, url, httpforbiddenhandler

I have following code:

```
$url = 'http://' . $host . ':' . $port . $params;
$results = file( $url );
```

I am getting following exception:

```
file(http://someurl.com/asd/asd): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
```

But I access URL(stored in $url variable) directly in browser, it is working perfectly fine. Why am I getting problem while accessing it from PHP?

Comment: URL file-access is maybe disabled in the server configuration (php.ini) --> allow_url_fopen = Off   (change to On)

Comment: @0xBAADF00D I think that is a different error message... the server he is accessing is probably either taking issue with his UA string or server ip. Probably some sort of anti-bot measure

Comment: As a completion to @0xBAADF00D maybe it's blocked if you don't send an User Agent, try `cURL`.

Comment: @Orangepill  try to access url from cURL with a "wtf" user agent : curl -A "kljslkdfjslfjdsklfjsldkf" http://... to see if the serveur block unknow user agent.

Comment: @0xBAADF00D think that should have gone to Awan :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message:

> HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

...is actually coming directly from the server that you're trying to access. So it's not a problem with PHP getting out to access an outside file.

It's instead more a problem of convincing the server to actually give you the file just like it would give it to a web browser.

There's a couple issues I would check:

1. Is the file password-protected? A web browser will save the password you enter, and allow you to re-access the URL without entering the password again, but PHP doesn't know what password to use.
2. Perhaps the server is restricting access from non-browsers by examining the user-agent string?
3. Perhaps the server is restricting access unless you're referred from another page on the same site?

One thing you could try would be using an [online HTTP header viewer tool](http://web-sniffer.net/) to try requesting the file directly. You can experiment with different headers, user-agents, etc to see if you can reproduce the problem.

If I had to guess, my money would be on the first problem - requiring a password. There's no way to know without knowing the actual URL though.

---

If you do figure out what it is that's blocking you from accessing the file, you should read up on the [http wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php), stream [contexts](http://php.net/manual/en/context.php), and particularly the [http stream context options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) to find out how to set the missing information from PHP. There are ways to specify a password, a user-agent, a referrer header, or even any random HTTP header you want.